# Python function to convert one or more columns

Tags: pandas

My goal is that specified columns in a dataframe get converted to numeric even if they have commas in them. In other words:

```
cols = ["x"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": ["1,000", "2,000"], "y": ["430","3,000"]})
df = data.float_convert(df, cols)
```

produces a df with this value:

```
pd.DataFrame({"x": ["1000", "2000"], "y": ["430","3,000"]})
```

Here's my function:

```
def float_convert(df, cols):
    return (df.loc[:,cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', "").astype(float)))
```

I can't understand why my code is not doing what I expect, and dont know if there's a much simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget assign it back

```
def float_convert(df, cols):
       df.loc[:,cols]=df.loc[:,cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', "").astype(float))
float_convert(df, cols)
df
      x      y
0  1000    430
1  2000  3,000
```

Comment: Ok! and, is that a good way to do it? It seems pretty involved. Do you have a cleaner approach?

Comment: @pitosalas this is how I will do it df=df.replace(',','',regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric)

Comment: I want to only touch columns mentioned in the variable cols. How do you modify your sample?

Comment: @pitosalas df['c']=df['c'].replace(',','',regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric) or df[['c','a']]=df[['c','a']].replace(',','',regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric)